# Execute Queries in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 5 queries 
all are dependent on one by one 
i have to run all queries in one time but it will be executed in sequence 
it's possible..?

please help me

Comment: SQL is executed in a top down manner. If you write the queries in the right order, they'll be run in the right order.

Answer (score 4):

You can build a stored procedure and execute each query in desired order by placing the queries in corresponding execution order

Answer (score 0):

you can use SSIS's sequence or process container to execute all of your SQL encapsulated in stored procedure at the same time, the provided screenshot show's processes in precedence,  but you can also design them to execute at the same time.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

> Imagination is more important than knowledge